# How to check if a point is inside a cylinder whose two caps are ellipses and have different length axes?

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

I am writing a 3D application where I need to check if a point is inside a capsule. Because a capsule can be divided into two half-ellipsoids and a cylinder, so the problem can be solved by checking a point against the three components. Checking if a point is inside an ellipsoid is easy, but I don't know how to deal with a cylinder?

Therefore, the question becomes:

In 3D space, there is a cylinder whose caps are two ellipses. The axes of the two ellipses are parallel but have different lengths. Given a point, how to check if it is inside this cylinder?

------------------- Additional Information ----------------------

It's not a regular capsule. The two caps of this capsule can be scaled separately along the default coordinate system's axes.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the parameterised equations of the cylinder and ellipses?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez All parameters are known. The height of the cylinder, the length of axes of the top and the bottom caps. The height of the top and the bottom ellipsoid.

Comment: How can the axes have different lengths but define a cylindre ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the OP means axis of the ellipsoids. This happens when they are in not parallel planes. Also if the "cylinder" is a truncated cone, which I think is not the OP case.

Comment: @Ripi2: I don't want to read the OP's mind. I want his answer. What he is describing is a weird shape.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. True! Now the OP has edited the question it seems it's about a truncated cone.

Comment: @Ripi2: I was commenting on the current version. A ruled surface with two elliptical caps is not uniquely defined and is usually neither a cylinder nor a cone.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It origins from a cylinder, the two caps of which can be separately scaled along the default coordinate system's axes, so I called it a cylinder.

Comment: I believe that your surface is neither a cylindre nor a cone, and it will not blend smoothly with the ellipsoids.

Comment: I suspect that your surface is like http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Capsule.html but caps are half-spheroids http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spheroid.html Am I right? If yes, then my answer is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an axis rotation so the main axis of the cylinder becomes one of the rotated axis (e.g. z axis).

Working with these transformed coordinates a point in the cylinder must:

- be below or on the top ellipsoid, and
- be over or on the low elllipsoid, and
- proyected into a plane perpendicular to cylinder main axis, it must be inside the ellipsoid defined by plane and cylinder.

Comment: I think OP meant that the "cylinder" 's cross-section is also elliptical.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have rotated the 'cylinder' so that it has the z axis as its axis, and that the ellipse at the top (z=h) is

```
sqr( x/a1) + sqr( y/b1) = 1
```

while the ellipse at the bottom (z=0) is

```
sqr( x/a0) + sqr( y/b0) = 1
```

Then at z (0<=z<=h) the ellipse will be

```
sqr( x/az) + sqr( y/bz) = 1
```

where

```
az = a0 + (z/h)*(a1-a0)
bz = b0 + (z/h)*(b1-b0)
```

so that if your test point is (x,y,z) with 0<=z<=h, it is in the cylinder iff

```
sqr( x/az) + sqr( y/bz) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to check whether point lies inside ellipsoid, then I don't see a problem.

If ellipsoidal cap is half of ellipsoid, just check that

```
(point is in ellipsoid) or (point is in cylinder)
```

If ellipsoidal cap is less than half of ellipsoid, check that

```
 ((point is in ellipsoid) and (point lies at outer side of base plane of cylinder)) or 
 (point is in cylinder)
```